# Please explain the recursive solution of finding the depth of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, depth

I found solution on this link.

[Get array's depth in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420156/get-arrays-depth-in-javascript/55420461#)
Due to inadequate reputation, I could not comment to ask for explanation through comments.

```js
function getArrayDepth(value) {
  return Array.isArray(value) ? 
    1 + Math.max(...value.map(getArrayDepth)) :
    0;
}
let testRy = [1,2,[3,4,[5,6],7,[8,[9,91]],10],11,12]

console.log(getArrayDepth(testRy))
```

Could you please explain why you are adding 1 and why you are using the Math.max function and the spread operator in the function above? How does this function work?

Comment: `1` means, that depth already equals to `1` because element is `Array`. `Math.max` gets as arguments a bunch of numbers and `...array` desturctures the array to numbers with comma between them like `1,2,3,4`. `value.map()` returns an `array` of numbers, each number will be nested arrays `depth` - as a result you will get the maximum and add that to `1` to get final result.

Comment: Use the function against something that is not and array, an array on depht 1. If you still have hard time figuring it out add a log before that retrun so you can see what the recusive ethod have been call on .

Comment: Note that this solution fails for nested empty arrays. The input `[[[[[[[]]]]]]]` has the output `-Infinity`, because `Math.max()` without arguments returns `-Infinity` and `1 + -Infinity //=> -Infinity`. You should add a guard to return `1` if the array is empty.

Comment: Thankyou Daniyal and xdTransform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a primer on recursion:

Recursion ultimately tries to solve the most basic form of the problem you can have and then gradually narrow down any complex problem to the most basic form. So you need the following (probably doesn't make complete sense until you read all of it):

1. You need to solve the base case.

   - the base case also serves as a *terminal condition*. You want to *stop* calling the function recursively at some point. Once you reach the base case you don't need to recurse any more.
2. You need a reduction step. You start with a big problem and you aim to go to the *base* form of it and solve it (the base case from 1.). If the current form is *not* the base, then it's not solvable - you need to reduce the problem a bit and call the function recursively.

So, in this case, the *base case* is that you get a value that is not an array. Since it's not an array, it doesn't have depth, hence you return zero. SOLVED! That is it.

However, what happens if you *do* get an array? Well, any array will have *some* depth. So, you can count one then get the contents of the array. That's the reduction step - you've reduced it from "I have an array of unknown depth" to "I have the contents of my array". When you recursively call `getArrayDepth` with the contents, you will re-evaluate whether you have an array or not and count appropriately. If you sum all the times you've had an array with depth of at least 1, you get the depth.

So far, we can solve the following things

Input: `42`
Output (depth): `0`
Why?: It's the base case - it's not an array, so we return `0` and don't recursively call the function.

Input: `[42]`
Output (depth): `1`
Why?: We have an array -> 
   count depth of 1 add the result of the recursive call with the contents `42` --> 
   it's the base case - it's not an array, so we return `0` and don't recursively call the function.
Going back, we've had `0` and `1` which totals `1`.

Input: `[[42]]`
Output (depth): `2`
Why?: We have an array -> 
   count depth of `1` and recursively call with the contents `[42]` --> 
   we have an array --> 
       count depth of 1 and recursively call with the contents `42` ---> 
       it's the base case - it's not an array, so we return `0` and don't recursively call the function.
Going back, we've had `0`, `1` and `1` which totals `2`.

And so on.

Now, as for why you use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Since arrays can have many elements, you use `.map` to call `getArrayDepth` on each of them. This will cause further recursion to work it out but at the end you will get an array of all the depths of the elements, so `["a", ["b"], [["c"]]]` will be transformed into `[1, 2, 3]`. Since you need to get the *total* depth, you need the highest number - this is achieved by using `Math.max` with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to return the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

The individual values in `testRy` are:

- 1
- 2
- [3,4,[5,6],7,[8,[9,91]],10]
- 11
- 12

On first execution of `getArrayDepth` with `testRy`, `Array.isArray(value)` will return true. So because this is true, we know we have at least depth 1 so that is why the `1+` is there. It then adds that to the the maximum value of calling `getArrayDepth` on each element in `testRy`. So that would look like:

```
getArrayDepth(1) => Array.isArray() false => 0
getArrayDepth(2) => Array.isArray() false => 0
getArrayDepth([3,4,[5,6],7,[8,[9,91]],10]) => Array.isArray() true => 1 + next max
```

so we hit another array, now we have at least another depth but we need to check if there are arrays in this array, so the cycle continues with this new array (it still has to finish `testRy`, but with the way it executes, it will go through this one first):

```
getArrayDepth(3) => Array.isArray() false => 0
getArrayDepth(4) => Array.isArray() false => 0
getArrayDepth([5,6]) => Array.isArray() true => 1 + next max
```

and this repeats until the end of `testRy`.

Answer (score 0):

Translating the code to English would sound something like this:

1. Is the input an array?

   1. yes - get the largest (`Math.max`) depth of each of the elements (`value.map(getArrayDepth)`) and increment it by 1 (`1 +`) to account for the current input array.
   2. no - there is no array, thus no depth, return `0`.

The spread operator is used to supply the array return value of `value.map(getArrayDepth)` as separate arguments. Since that is what `Math.max` expects.