# How to know if an array is single dimension or multiple dimension?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need your help arround array in JS.
I have a function where i need to check if the array passed in argument is one dimension or 2 dimension

let's say :

```
function test(array){
if(array is single dimension{
 console.log("Single dimension");
}else{
console.log("2Dimension");
```

and the following should display :

```
test([1,2,3]); // Should log "Single dimension"
test([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]); // Should log "2Dimension"
```

Any help will be really nice! Thank you!

Comment: do you have mixed arrays?

Comment: Are you asking for a creative custom solution? Or are you asking if there's some sort of JS API composition to solve this problem for you? If it's the former, then you should offer what you've started with. If it's the latter, then that should be added to your question for clarity sake.

Comment: @TobiahRex I just wanted to know if there is some "JS native API" who is doing the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to know if an array is single dimension or multiple dimension?

JavaScript doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays; it has arrays of arrays. There's a subtle difference between those two things. Even more, a JavaScript can have entries that are arrays and other entries that *aren't* arrays, making it only partially "multi-dimensional."

If you need to know that an array doesn't contain any arrays (e.g., is one-dimensional), the only way is to check every entry in it to see if that entry is an array:

```
if (theArray.every(entry => !Array.isArray(entry)) {
    // One dimensional
} else {
    // Has at least one entry that is an array
}
```

Here's an example of an array that only has *some* entries that are arrays and others that aren't:

```js
const a = [1, 2, ["a", "b"], 3];
console.log(a.length); // 4, not 5
console.log(Array.isArray(a[0])); // false
console.log(Array.isArray(a[2])); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach and check the first element for nested arrays.

```js
function getDimension([array]) {
    return 1 + (Array.isArray(array) && getDimension(array));
}    
    
console.log(getDimension([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(getDimension([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to this one 
[Get array's depth in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420156/get-arrays-depth-in-javascript)

You can use function like this one :

```
function getArrayDepth(value) {
  return Array.isArray(value) ? 
    1 + Math.max(...value.map(getArrayDepth)) :
    0;
}
```

Then simply

```
const testArray = [1,2,3];
if (getArrayDepth(testArray) > 1){
 console.log('One array');
}else{
  console.log('Array in array')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be checked like that:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const multiDimensional = [
  [1,2,3],
  [1,2,3]
];

const isMultiDimensional = (arr) => {
  const result = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (c.constructor === Array)
      a = true;

    return a;
  }, false)
  return result;
}

console.log(isMultiDimensional ([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(isMultiDimensional ([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]));
```